# Why does a border around a column in Bootsrap not go around the content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

W3school states the following:
 - Border - A border that goes around the padding and content

when adding a border around columns in bootstrap it seems that the border will go inward instead of outward why is that?

visual example:

[click here for jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLe9v04q/)

Html

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 border1">First</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 border2">Second</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 border3">Third</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 bordera">First</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 borderb">Second</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 borderc">Third</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.col-xs-4 {
background-color:grey;
}

.border1 {
border: 1px solid red;
}

.border2 {
border: 1px solid blue;
}
.border3 {
border: 1px solid green;
}

.bordera {
border: 3px solid red;
}
.borderb {
border: 3px solid blue;
}
.borderc {
border: 3px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `box-sizing:border-box` which bootstrap adds.

Try adding `box-sizing: content-box;` to your div.

```
.border1, .border2, .border3, .bordera, .borderb, .borderc{
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It all makes sense now